# R Shiny Leaflet - How to clear previous marker/circle/etc before adding a new one

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Fairly basic question but I cant seem to find the answer; I have an interactive map which saves coordinates on a click event, I'd like the old markers to disappear if the user clicks on a new part of the map.

Ive tried various things involving lists and if commands but no dice, Ive read about "reactive" elements, not sure how to impliment it, examples I tried didnt work. Any advice greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(leafletOutput("map")), 

server <- function(input, output, session){

#initial map output
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng =  -6.670972, lat =  54.693751, zoom=12) %>%
    addTiles(options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
    leafem::addMouseCoordinates()
}) #end render

observeEvent(input$map_click, {
    click <- input$map_click
    print(paste0(click$lat,", ",click$lng))
    x<-data.frame(col=paste0(click$lat,", ",click$lng))
    write.csv(x,"C:/test.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = TRUE)
    leafletProxy('map') %>%
      addMarkers(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, label = paste0(round(click$lat,5),", ",round(click$lng,5)),labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
      addCircles(lng=click$lng, lat=click$lat, group='circles', weight=1, radius=300, color='black', fillColor='red',fillOpacity=0.2, opacity=1)
}) #end observe
}) #end app
```

The code above works but creates a new marker each time

Comment: One quick approach to this is to add `clearMarkers()` and `clearShapes()` in the pipe after `leafletProxy('map')` and before adding the new marker and circle.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. I'd actually tried that before but forgot the  "%>%" after the ClearShapes(), thankyou!